# HTML Multi-select to Ajax URL

Tags: html, ajax, multi-select

Let's assume we have an HTML multi-select.

How to prepare an ajax request URL with the selected values from the multi-select. I'm using YUI dataTable, so I do not think I can use form serialization (but would not even want to even if I could)?
The URL generated should be the same as with a normal form submission with page refresh.

I did this but was hoping a better way with YUI was possible:

```
function createURLFromMultiSelect(ob, name) { 
  var url = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
      if (ob.options[ i ].selected) {
          url += "&" + name + "[]=" + ob.options[ i ].value;
    }  
  }
  return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name=value1&name=value2&name=value3
```

Comment: Well, OK. This is just what I want to do. How do I do it elegantly?

Comment: BTW, it should eb name[]=value1&name[]=value2&name[]=value3

Comment: No, it shouldn't. If you are using PHP and using PHP's built in form parsing library, then the name must end with the characters "[]" but those characters are part of the name, not separate to it.

Comment: yes ok. Depends on the name of the input and how you build your URL though. I understand you're assuming the input name to include the [].

Comment: If the input name doesn't include the [] part in the name (and you use PHP) then it isn't going to work when the non-JS fallback hits.

Comment: I think you're correct, it belongs in the element name, and I should not manually add it in the URL (even though I do not handle progressive enhancement or unobtrusive javascript  for now). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The name of your select can should end with [].  For example, `<select name="items[]">`
 Then in your php code, you simply access `$_POST['items'][$n];`  or `count($_POST['items']);` or whatever you want to do with the array.

--Dave

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my use case. I'm not submitting a web 1.0 form, I want to have a way to manually construct the URL for sending an ajax request. (or you are relying are form serialization, which I kind of eliminated from the solution).